# Can I save big json file directly to mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a web page with multiple controls which contains,text,images,attachments, and we allow customers to upload (drag and drop) attachments. I need to save theis data to mongo db. Till now , I was saving text data to one collection and saving attachments using GridFs separately.

I want to save all the data(text/images) including attachments (as json ) in base 64 encoding data as a single record.

Can I save this entire data as a single record into mongo db. The total file size could be more than 20MB (in case it has attachments).How can I achieve this?

Can I write entire data into json file and same it into mongo db using GridFs ?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I save this entire data as a single record into mongo db. The total file size could be more than 20MB (in case it has attachments).How can I achieve this?

The maximum size of a single BSON document in the current versions of MongoDB is [16MB](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents), hence, I'm afraid you cannot save it in a single document.

> Can I write entire data into json file and same it into mongo db using GridFs ?

This, on the other hand, you can do, though I don't know why would you. Your initial scheme (one document + files in GridFS) is the "normal" way of handling such cases, storing them in GridFS doesn't give you any edge: GridFS itself automatically splits documents into multiple chunks.